# load php data to javascript function to further used in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm making a school project, where I shall be able to load a php named: main_login.php through a javascript function called overvågning(), and then load the php into a div I've made. I can't seem to find anything which should be able to help me.
This is the stuff I've made so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Surveillance4you</title>

<style type="text/css">

            * {
                font-size: 20px;
                font-family: Arial;
            }

            #indhold {
                width: 560px;
        height: 560px;
        margin-left: 651px;
        margin-top: 270px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 0px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #indhold input {
            padding: 3px;
            margin: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }  
        body {color:#fff;}
</style>

<script>
function OutputInfo()
{
    document.getElementById("indhold").innerHTML="Lavet af:<br> Mads Schiellerup & Frederik Munck<br> Erhversskolen Nordsjælland HTX <br> 10-05-2014<br>Vejleder: Christian Obel"
}
function OutputForside()
{
document.getElementById("indhold").innerHTML="Surveillance4you er en hjemmeside som bruges til at live-streame en video af et overvågningskamera. Dette gøes ved hjælp af en opkobling til vores database, hvor du først kan lave en bruger, og herefter have mulighed for at kunne se diverse kameraer."

}
function overvågning()
{
    document.getElementById("indhold").innerid=MLogin
}
</script>


</head>
<body background="https://filemanager.one.com/api/webspace/1/drive/saxenkol.dk/data/Full%20Baggrund.png" onLoad="OutputForside()">

<input type="image"             src="https://filemanager.one.com/api/webspace/1/drive/saxenkol.dk/data/Menu%20-%20Forside.png" 
onClick="OutputForside()"
    style=" position: absolute; 
                top: 170px; 
                left: 660px;">

<input type="image"     src="https://filemanager.one.com/api/webspace/1/drive/saxenkol.dk/data/Menu%20-%20Overvågning.png"
onClick="MLogin"        style=" position: absolute; 
                top: 170px; 
                left: 860px;">

<input type="image"     src="https://filemanager.one.com/api/webspace/1/drive/saxenkol.dk/data/Menu%20-%20Info.png" 
onClick="OutputInfo()"      style=" position: absolute; 
                top: 170px; 
                left: 1060px;">


<div>   
    <?php

        $form = "";
        $form.= "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\">";
        $form.= "<div id=\"indhold\">";
        $form.= "</div>";
        $form.= "</form>";

        print $form;
    ?>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The PHP-file i want my function to get and sent to the container #indhold.

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1"         bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

New updated:

```
<?php
    function overvågning()
    {
        $form = "";
        $form.= "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\"><div id=\indhold\">";
        $form.= include 'main_login.php';
        $form.= "</div></form>";
        print $form;
    }

?>
```

And I've also changed:
    onClick="overvågning()"
So when I clicked on this image, it should show the php in container

Comment: You want the php compiled output to show up in javascript?

Comment: No, i want to you get data from main_login.php, then make a function overvågning() which happends when a image is onClick. This data shall then show up in a container "indhold"

Comment: I've updated the code, so you can see what php file i want too use

Comment: Yeah so you want the compiled the php code, and not the php code itself. So why not output the php into a hidden div and then have javascript read the innerHTML of the hidden div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Halløjsa. If I understand correctly you want to pass the user-input from your form to your javascript function but why are there no inputs and submit button within your form tags? If you were to use the php get method instead of post you could retrive the value from the submitted input directly from the url using the window.location method. See this article:
http://javascriptproductivity.blogspot.dk/2013/02/get-url-variables-with-javascript.html

EDIT:If you are not retrieving user inputs but simply want to load the log in file into the page use php include

```
<?php    
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\"><div id=\"indhold\">";
include 'main_login.php';
echo "</div></form>";
?>
```

Comment: Kinda. I want my function overvågning() to locate the main_login.php file, and then use the function on the onClick="overvågning()", which then should sent the php-script to my container #indhold. In the container on my website, there then should display a login platform(a table). :-)

Comment: I've updated the code, so you can see what php file i want too use

Comment: Several things looks wierd in your code. Your input type image is not nested in form tags if you are only using them for js dont use inputs just plain image tags or a button tag. Your php variable ($form) is changing all the time without concatenation or a loop  (only the closing form tag will be printed)

Comment: Instead of loading content in to your form with js which would require AJAX why not just use php include to load the external login file?

Comment: Edit to previous comment: Sorry I see you are concatenating your form variable. I really think the way to go is to use php include.

Comment: Okay, can you give me an example? So I know the idea about how to do the include, since I'm not quite sure how to.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example try this code instead of the print method

Comment: I've updated a extra thing in the topic, which i thought would do it, since I've choosed to call it.

Comment: I dont think you can use include within your $form variable as include is a method where the rest of your var is a string. replace the content of your new function with the code I added to the answer. That should work. Best of luck

Comment: Hmm I've tried set it in now as you say, but nothing happends when I try it out - I appreciate you taking time for me.
But I'm thinking, Can it be because that 'main_login.php' ain't described right? I mean the location of it, since my Index.php file and main_login.php file is on one.com file archive.

Comment: No problem just the full relative url to the file: include "/..../" etc. Or maybe absolute urls can be used if the files are on the same domain